# Example of a function which is not differentiable on parts of its domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

Can you provide me with an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is **not** piece-wise defined and differentiable on some parts of its domain and some parts not?

I am curious to know whether it is possible to say soemthing like this: "function f is differentiable until point x=5 but for values x>5  it is no longer differentiable".

(I know that you can achieve this with functions like $f(x)= x^{q \over p}, p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ at point $0$ but that is not what I am looking for.)

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: One problem is that being "not piece-wise defined" is not well-defined.

Comment: Going in the direction of [Qi Zhu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/470938/qi-zhu), I would say that a map defined by something for $x \le 5$ and something else for $x > 5$ is piecewise defined.

Comment: I doubt a satisfactory example exists, if as I apprehend, you are looking for a single formula in terms of familiar functions.  All the elementary functions, and even the special functions are infinitely differentiable almost everywhere they are defined.  They wouldn't be useful otherwise.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, I refer to the derivative not the function itself.

Comment: @QiZhu, what do you mean by that? $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},f(x)=x$ is not piece-wise defined but well-defined. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: How do you define "not piece-wise defined"?

Comment: @QiZhu, if you have no sub-functions which apply to different sets or intervals of the domain of the main function.

Comment: What is a subfunction? Do you know what a function is? A function is not a set of formulas.

Comment: I hope it becomes clear with an example of a piece-wise defined function: $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} f_1(x), & x\in M \\
         f_2(x), & x\not\in M\end{array}\right. .$$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are sub-functions.

Comment: As I've already said, it's just not well-defined what a "not piecewise defined function" is. I know what you are trying to say but trying to make it rigorous does not seem easy. Because again: a function is not a (set of) formula(s).

Comment: @QiZhu, then I don't understand why the above given definition of a not-piece-wise-defined function is not rigorous. It's very clear to say "no sub-functions which apply to different sets or intervals of the domain of the main function". Or you can put "mapping rule" instead of "sub-function" if you like. What's wrong with saying that a function is a set of formulas in the context of piece-wise-defined functions?

Comment: It's not "very clear" to me. A function $f:A \to B$ is defined to be a subset of $A \times B$ such that it is what one expects. There are hence too many possibilities to define functions. I could for instance (this is a stupid example) assign an open interval to some place on earth, biject this to $\mathbb{R}$ and let the height of that place be the output of the function...

Comment: It's also not a problem to rewrite your function into a "not piecewise-defined" function, as in $f = \mathbb{1}_M f_1 + \mathbb{1}_{M^C} f_2$ where $\mathbb{1}_{\cdot}$ denotes the indicator function as usual.

Comment: There is just not a rigorous way to define exactly what a "not piecewise defined" function is - at least I cannot see an easy way to define that.

Comment: @QiZhu, Ah okay I got the point, thx for your pacience and the explanations :)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to conjure up an example, but realized that i was just rewriting "piecewise defined" functions in a "not-piecewise" way. Here is an example: Consider a differentiable function $f$ and a continous but nowhere differentiable function $g$ (for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Then the function $h(x):= max(f(x),g(x))$ is differentiable on the open set $\{x| f(x)>g(x)\}$ and not differentiable on the open set $\{x|f(x)<g(x)\}$.

But the question is now, do you consider $max(f,g)$ to be piecewise or not? Clearly it can be defined piecewise, but could also be defined by the formula
$$max(f(x),g(x)) = \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2} + \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2} $$

Comment: differentiability at points, where $f(x)=g(x)$ depends on choice of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0):

What about

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x \le 5\\
1 & x \in \mathbb Q \text{ and } x > 5\\
0 & x \notin \mathbb Q \text{ and } x > 5
\end{cases}$$

It is differentibale for $x \le 5$ and not even continuous for $x > 5$.

Another one... consider the map $f$ defined in [this post](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/function-everywhere-continuous-nowhere-differentiable/) for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$. it is continuous and never differentiable for $x > 0$ but differentiable for $x \le 0$.

*Note: however those may be seen as piecewise defined.*

Comment: No, that's not what I am looking for.